# Angular UI-Router update parent scope from child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

here is a sample setup for my app

```
 .state('base', {
      controller: 'resourceCtrl'
      view: 'resource.html'
 }
 .state('base.edit', {
      controller: 'resourceEditCtrl'
      view: 'resourceEdit.html'
 }
```

Inside resourceCtrl, I assign $scope.resource to a promise of an api call to get a single resource.

```
 API.getResource(id).then(resource){
      $scope.resource = resource;
 }
```

In resourceEditCtrl, I then use this inherited $scope variable of $scope.resource to edit it

```
 $scope.$watch('resource', function(r){
      if(r){
           $scope.resourceToEdit = angular.copy(r);

           $scope.save = function(){
                //some changes are made to $scope.resourceToEdit in the view
                //eg: change the title, description, etc
                
                ////////
                //////// THIS IS THE PART THAT DOESNT WORK
                ////////
                //////// try to update parent $scope.resource with newly saved value
                $scope.resource = $scope.resourceToEdit;

                $scope.transitionTo('base');

           }
      }
 }
```

When i transition back to baseCtrl, the newly saved values are gone, and its still in the original state. If I refresh, the values will be updated because of the call to the API, but ideally, I would be able to update the parent scope variable to be synced with the newly saved value, so a refresh isn't necessary.

Is this possible?

### EDIT:

Here is a demo plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/8OK1VR8tLN4BAyQaMs3d?p=preview

Comment: Check out $scope.$broadcast and $scope.$on for communication between different controllers and other modules

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to to something like:

```
$scope.$parent.resource = $scope.resourceToEdit
```

given that base is the parent of your resource controller.

Comment: This worked for me, but it seems "hacky". Is this the Angular way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The more angular way to do this is to create a service that gets injected into both of your controllers.  Since the injected object is a singleton the data is shared/updated when each controller updates the data:

http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/controllers/sharing-code-between-controllers-using-services.html

Answer (score 2):

My way is to write a function in the parent which modifies its $scope, since the parent scope is always available in the child, but not viceversa

### Parent scope

```
$scope.parentVar = 'A value';

$scope.modifyParentScope = function(variable) {
    $scope.parentVar = variable;
}
```

### Child scope

```
$scope.childVar = 'A new value';

$scope.modifyParentScope($scope.childVar);
```

That way you avoid `$scope.$parent` problems. Of course the other way is to use rosswil's example and create a `factory` or `service` which shares all the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Inject $rootScope in both the controller and use it normally.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to send all the variables from the children to the parent through events and affect them to the parent scope and only this scope. This way I never have conflicts or inconsistencies between scopes.

@Pieter's solution doesn't work if you start naming your `ui-view`s.